# Dielectric constant of crystals: Feynman's mistake?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric, dipole, dipole-moment

Feynman mentioned in [his lecture](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_11.html) that we can, in some way, obtain dielectric constant of crystals by summing up the electric field due to dipoles. For example, equation **(11.33)** from above link shows the sum for $\rm BaTiO_3$. He also mentioned that the same calculation for simple cubic results to a factor
of 1/3 in simple cubic crystals.

However, if one calculates the exact field due to dipoles and integrate for all the neighbors in **simple cubic lattice** (e.g. using $(3(p.r)r-p)/r^3$ instead of the one he used $p/r^3$), the result would be zero field due to surrounding dipoles.

I cannot find anyone extending or using this approach to figure out what I am missing. Also equation 15 and 16 in [these notes](https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2014_Dielectric_Properties_of_Insulators.pdf) proves the sum $(3(p.r)r-p)/r^3$ is zero. Moreover, in a simple cubic lattice, the simplest example is to consider **6 nearest neighbor dipoles** (6 neighbors: top, bottom, left, right, front and back) which gives zero field.

Is this a mistake in Feynman lectures?

To show the sum for 6 neighbors, one can evaluate equation 6 times for 6 neighbors:

```
        Rs = np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
                  [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
                  [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
                  [-1.,  0.,  0.],
                  [ 0., -1.,  0.],
                  [ 0.,  0., -1.]])
    pdir = np.array([0, 0, 1.0])
    for ii in range(len(Rs)):
        u = Rs[ii]
        d = 1.0
        Efield_i = (3 * pdir.dot(u) * u - pdir) / (d * d * d)
        print("Efield_i", Efield_i)
```

Which gives with zero sum:

```
Efield_i [0. 0. 2.]
Efield_i [ 0.  0. -1.]
Efield_i [ 0.  0. -1.]
Efield_i [-0.  0. -1.]
Efield_i [ 0. -0. -1.]
Efield_i [-0. -0.  2.]
```

**Edit:** Please notice this question is not about E-field of dipoles, but about the approach and assumptions Feynman used to calculate dielectric constant.

Comment: *if one calculates the exact field due to dipoles and integrate for all the neighbors in simple cubic lattice*...how many particles did you  integrate over $6$ or full lattice (haven't gone through the ref yet, will answ later)

Comment: I mean lets just consider a single point in simple cubic. The simplest case is to consider only nearest neighbors (which is 6: top, bot, left, right ...)  Then we will see the sum is zero. If we do numerically for larger distance, it is also zero.

Comment: I am not sure, but is it possible you are doing the sum assuming that you are in the center of the crystal? You should think about the field away from this symmetric point.

Comment: I think if you do the simple summation, you would see for yourself for sure that it is 0.

Comment: @Roy: if the calculation is simple, why not show it to us, in order to get help? This is not a site for posting excercises to others...

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not show us your 6 nearest neighbour calculation, I am not able to tell anything about possible flaws in it. However, Maxwell's equations (namely Gauß' law) generally tell us that
$$\vec \nabla\cdot \vec E=4\pi\rho$$
that is, if $\vec E=0$ (which is what you claim to be your result) for a certain distribution, then inevitably
$$\rho = \frac{1}{4\pi}\vec \nabla\cdot \vec E=0$$
which is not a dipole distribution, nor any distribution of any charges, at all. Please compare this to the known charge distribution of a set of dipoles:
$$\rho(\vec r) = \sum_i \vec p_i \cdot \vec\nabla \delta(\vec r-\vec r_i)$$

Also, in your second reference, after equation (14) you can read

> Now  we  consider  the  field  that  acts  on  the  atom  at  the  center  of  the  sphere. If  all  dipoles  are parallel  to  the  z  axis  and  have  magnitude p,  the z component  of  the  field  at  the  center  due  to  all other dipoles is...

In other words, what follows is a very special calculation for a very special configuration: not only is a spherical crystal, i.e. charge/dipole distribution assumed, but also the value of the field strength is only calculated at the center of this symmetric distribution. Hence, after equation (15)

> The  latter  equation  comes  from  the  fact  that  the x,  y,  z directions  are  equivalent  because  of  the symmetry of the lattice and of the sphere

That is, the field of a set of dipoles does **NOT** vanish in general (that would be ridiculous), but only in this special setting, which is dedicated to calculating the **local** field at one atom site, and **not** the macroscopic electric field (which is described by the dielectric permittivity).

The reason (the Lorentz theory of dielectrics) for this special assumption follows later on after equation (17), where an artifical distinction is made between the rapidly fluctuating near-field of an atom, and the smooth far-field. This distinction is made by "drawing" a more or less arbitrary sphere around the atom in question, which clearly shows the spherical symmetry used earlier.

To reinterate, what vanishes is not the dipole field in general, but only the fluctuating near-field inside an artificial sphere around a specific atom.

The general behavior of dielectrics, as already indicated in my comment, is also described after equation (4):

> From the macroscopic point of view the dielectric can be considered as a material with no net charges in the interior of the material and induced negative and positive charges on the left and right surfaces of the dielectric.

This clearly disproves any general statement like "the sum of those polarizations are zero" because then there could not be surface charges.

Answer (score 3):

Despite your formula being wrong you get the correct result in this case. But all you did was calculate the electric field at one single point $\mathbf{r} = (0, 0, 0)^T$ which certainly doesn't say much about the field as a whole. The electric field of a single dipole $\mathbf{d}$ at $\mathbf{r}_0$ is given by
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0) \mathbf{d}\cdot (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0) - \mathbf{d} |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0|^2}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0|^5}
$$
If you redo your code like that an use a variable location at which to evaluate the electric field instead of choosing $(0,0,0)$ you will find a non zero field. It would look like this in the xy plane for example [image]

In the lecture Feynman is talking about an infinite chain along the z-axis of dipoles in the z direction and says that for a single dipole if you're a distance $r=z$ away from the dipole along the z-axis the field would be
$$
\mathbf{E}(0,0,z) \propto \frac{3 z d_z z \mathbf{e}_z - d_z\mathbf{e}_z z^2}{z^5} = \frac{2z^2 d_z}{z^5}\mathbf{e}_z = \frac{2d}{z^3}\mathbf{e}_z
$$
so the formula is not approximate, it's calculated for this special case. He then sums over the dipoles in this one chain and reasons that the other chains only contribute very little to the electric field.

Comment: First, the equation is correct. It is just that I used unit vectors (u). What you said is obvious but irrelevant. The question is about Feynman's approach for dielectrics. He used the approximate equation and found some value and claimed other components decay exponentially.

Comment: I added a justification of what Feynman did in my post.

Comment: Thanks but that part is not the issue. He says the effect of neighboring chains decays exponentially. But if you calculate numerically, they are not and they cancel out the main one. I did the numerical calculation, it is just 6 neoghbors.

Comment: In that case, refer to my plot. The electric field does not cancel out everywhere but just in the origin coincidentally. He also links eq 7.44 which shows the exponential decay and it's derived mathematically not numerically. One array of dipoles is also not the same as a chain.

Comment: Feynman is calculating at each atom site. Of course E-field is not zero everywhere. This is more about Feynman's approach.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple. Consider just two neighbouring dipoles in the $+z$ and $-z$ direction, where $z$ also happens to be the direction of polarisation.

With your formula, they cancel. The field due to a dipole a distance $r$ along its axis of polarisation is equal and opposite to the field a distance $r$ in the opposite direction.

But if you think about it and draw the picture, they clearly add. The field at $(0,0,0)$ due to a $z-$direction dipole at $(0,0,a)$ is the same as the field at $(0,0,0)$ due to a similar dipole at $(0,0,-a)$.

In your formula you need to distinguish carefully between $\vec r$ as the vector from the dipole to the point of interest, and the vector from the point of interest to the dipole. There is an important minus sign between them. If you incorporate this correctly in your algebra or your program you will get a non-zero answer, as you must.

Comment: No they don't cancel. The one on top and bottom add up. The 4 dipoles at sides also adds up but in opposite direction. The sum of up and down then is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here is first the calculation which I guess the OP did, and then the reason why it is the wrong calculation, and then a better calculation.

First let's put dipoles at $(\pm r,0,0)$,
$(0,\pm r,0)$ and $(0,0,\pm r)$ and consider the field at the origin.
We suppose the dipoles are all aligned in the $x$ direction, each of size $p$.

Let's drop the $1/4\pi \epsilon_0$, so we say the field of each dipole is
$$
{\bf E}_1 = \frac{3 ({\bf p} \cdot \hat{\bf r})\hat{\bf r} - {\bf p}}{r^3}
$$

At the origin the pair on the x axis give a net electric field
$2 \times 2p / r^3 = 4p/ r^3$, in the $+x$ direction. Each of the others gives an electric field $p/ r^3$, in the $-x$ direction. Hence the total field from the 6 dipoles under consideration, at the origin, is zero. Interesting!

However, if we imagine these 6 dipoles are part of a cubic lattice, then we have calculated their effect at the location exactly on top of one of the other dipoles in the lattice! So this is not a great place to do the calculation!

For a more useful insight, consider a location at the centre of a square of dipoles,  or at the centre of a cube with dipoles at the corners. In this case one has to track the signs both in ${\bf p} \cdot \hat{\bf r}$ and in $\hat{\bf r}$. One finds that the field components in the $y$ and $z$ directions cancel out (as could be seen by symmetry) but the $x$ component does not.

Finally, the case of a uniform polarization is well known (and easier to calculate).

Comment: Actually if you look at 2d plot provided by one answer, we can see it is 0. I did for much more dipoles and it is still 0 at each atom site.

Comment: @Roy But it is not zero at the centre of a cube of dipoles, and the average over all locations is not zero.

Comment: Feynman is calculating at each site. Of course, I am not saying E-field is zero everywhere.

Comment: @roy ok; at a site there in cubic lattice of spacing $a$ there are 6 nearest neighbours giving zero net field at the centre, and next out there are 12 next-nearest neighbours at the corners of 3 squares of side $2a$, all giving non-zero total at the centre, in same direction. The next 8 (corners of cube of side $2a$) also give non-zero field. etc. Another way to set it up is to consider planes of charge of alternating sign.